# Vue.js don't receive Socket.io event from Flask

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, flask, socket.io

I created simple Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import socketio

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'very-secret'
CORS(app)

sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*', logger=True, async_mode=None)
app.wsgi_app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, app.wsgi_app)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)
    sio.emit('hello_world', {'data': 'A'})

@app.route('/api/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    sio.emit('hello_world', {'data': 'B'})

    return jsonify({
        'ok': True,
        'data': {
            'message': "Alive!"
        }
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

and then I create simple Vue app, vue-cli starter with only differences in main.js where I added connection to socket server:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueSocketIO from "vue-socket.io"

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(
    new VueSocketIO({
        debug: true,
        connection: "http://localhost:5000"
    })
)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)  
}).$mount('#app')
```

and HelloWorld.vue component where I changed script part:

```
export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
        msg: String
    },
    sockets: {
        connect () {
            console.log("Connected")
        },
        hello_world (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.$socket.emit("hello_world", {"data": "test!"})
    }
}
```

When I start Flask app and then start Vue app I have following log inside Flask:

```
$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 386-990-364
connect  dcf04629bd8245239789ae7c59fce915
emitting event "hello_world" to all [/]
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 19:15:22] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N8p5ICr HTTP/1.1" 200 -
received event "hello_world" from dcf04629bd8245239789ae7c59fce915 [/]
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 19:15:22] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N8p5IE0&sid=dcf04629bd8245239789ae7c59fce915 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Which shows that Vue connected and Flask received this message emited by Vue, but my problem is that Vue don't receive anything from this server even though that server emited hello_world. It doesn't run neither connect nor hello_world functions inside sockets block in HelloWorld component. What I am missing here?

Comment: What version of VueSocketIO are u using? If you are `3.0.5>`, downgrade to `3.0.5`, version 3.0.5+ seems like breaking the library, read more here: https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/250

Comment: @Owl you are right :) 3.0.5 works with same code problem is in the lib. Thanks a lot!